# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException when testing scala future

Tags: scala

I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class NodeScalaSuite extends FunSuite with ScalaFutures {
```

Within it, I added this test to check a method returning a future:

```
  test("Any should return the first future") {
    val p = Promise[Int]()
    p completeWith Future.any(List(Future{wait(2000); 1}, Future{wait(1); 2}))
    whenReady(p.future) {x =>
      assert(true)
    }
  }
```

(I made the assert `true` just for simpler debugging.)

When I run the test suite I am getting this error:

```
[info]   The future returned an exception of type: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException.
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs for `java.lang.Object#wait` it

> throws `IllegalMonitorStateException` if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

Which means `wait` should be called inside `synchronized` block. Something like `synchronized { wait(2000) }` should work but I think what you really want to do is to use `Thread.sleep(2000)`. `wait` is meant to be used in combination with `notify` and `notifyAll` for synchronizing access to shared resource from multiple threads. It releases the object's monitor so another thread can execute the same synchronized block.